# Pandas Pivot_Table "Function does not reduce" error

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Please see below data frame i am working on:

```
NeededColumns  = DataFrame({
 'LABLE': ['ABC_123', 'ABC_123', 'ABC_123', 'ABC_123', 'ABC_123'],
 'RAW_ID_3': [2, 71, 376, 526, 651],
 'RAW_SCRIBE': ['K9FDB002WFD7',
                'X4PH8071KOE4',
                'AZ0GR376JKH2',
                'BA5QF526JKG2',
                'AY7WC651JKA1'],
 'SPC_LOT': ['D1111111', 'D2222222', 'D3333333', 'D4444444', 'D5555555'],
 'SPC_LOT7_x': ['D111111', 'D222222', 'D333333', 'D444444', 'D555555'],
 'SPC_OPERATION': ['115', '115', '115', '115', '115'],
 'SPC_PRODUCT': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'],
 'SPC_RAW_VALUE': [0.22, 0.552, 0.535, 0.457, 0.35100000000000003],
 'SPC_TXN_DATE_x': ['2015-09-13 08:22:26',
                    '2015-09-13 08:30:26',
                    '2015-09-13 10:10:37',
                    '2015-09-13 22:30:17',
                    '2015-09-13 23:18:32']})
```

While i am trying to run following command:

```
Pivoted_TXN_DATES = pd.pivot_table(NeededColumns, 
  index=['SPC_LOT', 'SPC_LOT7_x', 'RAW_SCRIBE', 'RAW_ID_3',
         'SPC_PRODUCT'],
  columns='SPC_OPERATION',
  values='SPC_TXN_DATE_x',
  aggfunc=lambda x: x).reset_index()
```

I am getting "Function does not reduce" error. What am i doing wrong
Please help

Comment: Can you post you data frame?

Comment: Thank you, Joe. Just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data works fine without any error, since it don't have grouped return I guess. But, I could see your aggregate function don't have reducer.

```
aggfunc=lambda x: x
```

Basically above function is not a aggregate function.

Few example of aggregate functions are,

```
aggfunc=lambda x: sum(x)  #or  'sum
'mean' #..etc
```